# iOS, how to got the magnifier event while touch TextView or TextField

Tags: ios, swift, touch

what's the mechanism of the magnifier? it seem not introduce details in official document, anyone help ? Many thanks.

Comment: Tap and hold to see the magnifier

Comment: I meaning if it can be track in app code ? eg, while user touch show the magnifier then I can know the magnifier captured text content , etc